# Is Trigun Stampede a remake of the 1998 series or a sequel?

Tags: trigun

The day before yesterday they started airing "Trigun Stampede". How does this series relate to the 1998 series? Is it a remake or a sequel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's technically a remake of both the anime and manga.

The new series a direct adaptation of the Trigun and Trigun Maximum manga. The original anime series ended before the manga and had a lot of filler. This new series is intended to follow more closely with the original source material by Yasuhiro Nightow.